# Search number in a varchar field using LIKE statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

Good morning,i have a little problem with a query to finding a record within a varchar field.

My table is composed of two field: **codice** and **giacenza** where  codice is a varchar field type.

I need to find all the record start with a number.

The query i have tried is:

```
SELECT codice,giacenza FROM prodotti WHERE codice like 'AC%' OR '160%'
```

and this:

```
SELECT codice,giacenza FROM prodotti WHERE codice like 'AC%' OR '160_'
```

but returned me ALL the record and not only the row start with AC and 160. If i delete the OR '160%' or the OR '160_' the query return me the right record: only the row start with AC.

I have read after a research with google,that you can not use the wildcard with a number. It's that correct?

There's a method to resolve my problem with this query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this one you miss the `like keyword` with OR - `SELECT codice,giacenza FROM prodotti WHERE codice like 'AC%' OR like '160%'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your query is

```
SELECT codice,giacenza FROM prodotti WHERE codice like 'AC%' OR '160%'
```

when processed the codition will be treated as

```
        ( codice like 'AC%') // codition 1  which will True or false 
      OR ('160%')   // condition 2 will always true 
   one codition True in OR means expression true for all
```

which  means ('160%')  will always result true for all rows

query should be like this

```
SELECT codice,giacenza FROM prodotti WHERE codice like 'AC%' OR  codice like  '160%'
```

Answer (score 3):

```sql
SELECT codice,
       giacenza
FROM prodotti
WHERE codice LIKE 'AC%'
  OR codice LIKE '160%'
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO Victor. The site allows some nice code formatting. It makes questions and answers look much better and also easier to read. Please consider looking into it :)

Comment: I thought enough to enter the OR, not having to repeat many times the statement. thanks